# Hadoop Cluster timeout restart

Tags: hadoop, service, ambari

I try to restart a Hadoop Cluster using Ambari.

Several services (Hive, Spark, Yarn,...) are killed due to timeout during the starting phase.

Stderr :

> python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 2700 secs

Stdout (after 2700s - 45 min, only 6/22 user are treated ):

```
2019-12-31 14:11:16,113 - Group['spark'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2019-12-31 14:11:16,113 - Group['hadoop'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2019-12-31 14:11:16,113 - Group['bigr'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2019-12-31 14:11:16,114 - Group['users'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2019-12-31 14:11:16,114 - Group['knox'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2019-12-31 14:11:16,114 - User['hive'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2019-12-31 14:24:24,671 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2019-12-31 14:30:43,580 - User['oozie'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': ['users']}
2019-12-31 14:38:52,952 - User['ams'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2019-12-31 14:45:43,558 - User['tauser'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2019-12-31 14:54:11,647 - User['dsmuser'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
```

I have incremented the value of `agent.package.install.task.timeout` property in `/etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties`file.

I don't understand why the `User check/creation` step is so long (about 7-8 min per user) !

I think the corresponding code is here : [python/resource_management/core/providers/accounts.py](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/branch-2.0.0/ambari-common/src/main/python/resource_management/core/providers/accounts.py)

Any clue ?

In advance, thank you for your help ;-)

*(HDP Version : BigInsights-4.1.0.0)*

Comment: _"I don't understand why the User check/creation step is so long"_ >> does your Linux setup use bindings to an LDAP directory (via SSSD or Centrify)? If yes, can you exclude well-known Hadoop system accounts and groups (`hive`, `spark` etc) from the binding attempts?

Comment: The admin have detected some problems with `winbind` services ; after a simple restart of this service all is ok. Thank's